# Heroku deployment - Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I was started using bootstrap version 4. And started receiving this error deploying to Heroku. my stylesheet is custom.css.scss. App works in development with not problem. Issued did not start to upgraded to bootstrap v4. 
When I was using the bootstrap v3 I did not have this problem with deployment ever.I have spend lot of reviewing different suggestions from other posts to no avail.

bootstrap.custom.css.scss file

```
 @import "bootstrap";
```

applications.scss

```
 /*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

application.js

```
  = require jquery
  = require tether
  = require bootstrap-sprockets
  = require jquery_ujs
  = require turbolinks
  = require_tree .
```

Error from heroku deployment

```
rake aborted! 
Sass::SyntaxError:File to import not found or unreadable:bootstrap-sprockets.
remote: Load paths:
remote: /tmp/build_9899a15a0b71b25c23a9b8dfc6d02e80/app/assets/images
remote:/tmp/build_9899a15a0b71b25c23a9b8dfc6d02e80/app/assets/javascripts
remote:/tmp/build_9899a15a0b71b25c23a9b8dfc6d02e80/app/assets/stylesheets
remote:/tmp/build_9899a15a0b71b25c23a9b8dfc6d02e80/vendor/assets/javascripts
remote:/tmp/build_9899a15a0b71b25c23a9b8dfc6d02e80/vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

Gemfile

```
 gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'sass-rails', '>= 5.0'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'turbolinks'
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
 gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
```

Installed gems

```
 gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3'
 gem 'sass', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.21'
 gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.0'
 source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.1.0'
 end
 gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
 gem 'font-awesome-rails', '~> 4.4.0.0'
 gem 'pry-rails', :group => :development
 gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '~> 6.0.3'
 gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.2'
 gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
 gem 'simple_form'
```

Comment: Is that your complete `application.scss`? If it is you're missing a `/*`. Did you accidentally delete the first line?

Comment: Accidentally left the line off wile typing.  I just updated the post.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to stick with the @import method for your application.scss file. Check this blog post for more information:

https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/structure-your-sass-files-with-import

Looks like the rails team also would suggest going down the @import path.

Answer (score 1):

We've deployed `bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha` successfully on Heroku and use the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.coffee
#= require tether
#= require bootstrap

#app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass
@import bootstrap
```

We don't use the `bootstrap` gem, we use the direct implementation from `rails-assets`:

---

As a *strong* recommendation, you'd be much better pulling any "asset" gems directly through their repos using [`Rails Assets`](http://rails-assets.org):

```
#Gemfile
source "https://rails-assets.org"

gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap', ">= 4.0.0.alpha.2"
gem 'rails-assets-tether'
```

Comment: Tried this did not fixed the problem. Still get this error.                                                                rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.

Comment: Did you remove `require bootstrap-sprockets`?

Comment: Interesting. Did you replace your gems with the ones I suggested?

Comment: I got to work after push and commit to git. Now my custom.css.scss stylesheet is not working.

Comment: Okay so where do you call custom? In your layout or in your application.css?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100902/discussion-between-user3905353-and-rich-peck).